# How do you add a SAML relayState using the (relatively) new Spring-Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

My question is comparable to this question that was asked a while ago: [Spring Security SAML2, sending language code in <Extensions> -element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391256/spring-security-saml2-sending-language-code-in-extensions-element/73606332#73606332).

In the old OpenSAML and openSAML-extensions libraries it was relatively easy to add a relayState to your SP-initiated SSO. This was done by making a overriding the `WebSSOProfileOptions` in the `SAMLEntryPoint` class and setting a relayState on the `MessageContext`. However, in the new library I'm unable to find out how to do this. I have tried a bunch of different options, done a few tutorials and the read the docs, but since I'm relatively new to Spring and SAML, it has been quite difficult to find.

I'd love to find out how to do it. Currently I'm using `samesite=none` cookies to match the response to the request. However, using a relayState seems to be much more elegant and less prone to errors.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I'm using this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.0-RC1/servlet/saml2/index.html library